# Activity going in loop when device orientation is changed from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, orientation, landscape-portrait

I have an activity which is supposed to be in landscape mode.

> code for the Activity

```
public class SessionActivity extends BaseActivity {
@Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

> Manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.SessionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
</activity>
```

*BaseActivty extends AppCompatActivity.*

When I call start this activity through intent, this activity goes in loop. onDestroy is called after `onCreate` and then `onDestroy` again and the same thing repeats when device orientation is changed from portrait to landscape. This is only happening in very few devices not in all the devices.

Any suggestions on why it is happening or how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps to make your app support orientations. You can not just expect your app to behave same way it is working in portrait mode. 
Check this [doc](https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a) for more details.

Also please make sure to make landscape files separately for landscape support. For that you can check this [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts)

Answer (score 0):

You can add below line in manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```